# Jquery Loop , condition and assigning to variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have an array after `dd()` **in php** it show like this array:

```
1 [▼0 => "1,18,187,188,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209,210,211,212,19,20,21,22,23,24"]
```

now I want to loop the array and pass only those values which are more than 200.
Here is the code

```
 $('#btnSave').on('click', function () {
   var checkedIds = mytree.getCheckedNodes();
   $('#userData').val(checkedIds);
 });
```

where `#userData` is a hidden field and `checkedIds` has the above values.

How to loop and make a condition to assign only the desired values to `#userData`

Comment: Your array has only one element and it is a comma delimited string. There are plenty of resources that explain how to turn a string like that into an actual array.

Comment: Please do not tag questions with improper tags just to get them more available. `php` tag is redundant here.

Comment: yes, if i selected two nodes in treeview it shows the following   array:1 [▼
        0 => "1,18,187,188,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209,210,211,212,19,20,21,22,23,24,9,90,298,299,91,300,301,92,302,303,93,304,94,305,306,95,307,96,308,97,309 ◀"
      ] in one element . i will try to search on string to array. if u have possible soultion please

Comment: @biesior I'd beg to differ. The source of the data is an array coming from PHP. Reformatting data into a desired shape is best done at the source whenever possible, to relieve the client of any extra work.

Comment: Ismail, I can advise you to have a look at [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, instead of using `dd()` encode the array into JSON and put it into an element's data attribute (with proper escaping): `<a data-array="<?php escape(json_encode($array))">...</a>`.
Then in js, you can decode the JSON again: `const array = JSON.parse(element.getAttribute('data-array'))`.

Comment: Putting a value into an otherwise irrelevant DOM element does not seem a good way to go about this.  You can put it directly in a js variable `const array = JSON.parse("<?php escale(json_encode($array,....`